# Backgroundcolor doesn't show up on a View inside CardView

Tags: android, android-xml, android-cardview

- I am creating a simple layout inside `cardview` with some views in it .Whenever I add some color to the background of the `view` it doesn't show up!

Layout XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/hor_divider"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/redColor"             // it doesn't show up
            android:elevation="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_type"
            style="@style/title_text"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/hor_divider"
            tools:text="Text" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            style="@style/SlideButton"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_type"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_32dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/hor_divider"
            android:text="Next"
            app:icon="@drawable/right_double_arrow_icon"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconSize="12dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/colorBlack" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/img" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

- `<View>` background color only shows in preview but not on real device.

Comment: remove "view" which is not showing and add it below imageview, also remove elevation from view(just cut and paste)

Comment: it is perfectly working on real device..try debugging on another device too

Comment: Have you tried the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Try these it might help  :

Clean your project by

Build > Clean Project

```
    OR
```

Rebuild your project by

Build > Rebuilt Project

```
    OR
```

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart >  Invalidate and Restart